# How to use ConstraintSet to set what like app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

Now,here is my question.

[image]

how can I use `ConstraintSet`'s connect to set attr like `'app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setId(R.id.text_id);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(constraintLayout);
set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
constraintLayout.addView(textView);
set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```